# How to build an accurate iPhone strobe light using swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to build video stroboscopy app to power the light source on an otolaryngolgy endoscope. https://youtu.be/mJedwz_r2Pc shows an example of what a traditional stroboscopy system does. It flashes at 0.5 HZ below the fundamental frequency of the patient to induce a slow-motion effect that allows clinicians to visualize the motion of the cords and mucosal wave. To do this I need to strobe at roughly 120 to 250 HZ.

I have used the printed functions with counters to verify my frequencies. When I comment out my code connecting the functions to the torch, I get an accurate frequency. When I uncomment the torch code, I lose accuracy. I do not understand why the torch functions are slowing down the strobe. Any insight or help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class StrobeLights {
  var counter: Int = 0
  var timer: Timer
  var isStrobing: Bool
  var isLightOn: Bool
  var frequency: Double
  var start = DispatchTime.now()
  var end = DispatchTime.now()
  var active: Bool





  init (){
    self.counter = 0
    self.timer = Timer()
    self.isStrobing = false
    self.isLightOn = false
    self.frequency = 200
    self.active = false
  }

  // Start Strobe process
  func toggleStrobe () {
    if isLightOn == true {
      self.isLightOn = false
      self.timer.invalidate()
      print("Turning timer off")
      self.end = DispatchTime.now()
      let nanoTime = end.uptimeNanoseconds - start.uptimeNanoseconds
      let timeInterval = Double(nanoTime) / 1_000_000_000
      print("I counted this high \(counter) in this many seconds \(timeInterval) ")
      //toggleTorch(on: false)
      counter = 0
      incrementCounter()
    } else {
      self.isLightOn = true
      // change made by removing frequecy --> 10
      self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1/frequency, target: self, selector: #selector(incrementCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
      print("Turning timer on")
      self.start = DispatchTime.now()
      //toggleTorch(on: true)
    }
  }



  // Increase counter by one

  @objc func incrementCounter () {
    self.toggleTorch(on: false)
    self.counter += 1
    //print("\(self.counter)")
    self.toggleTorch(on: true)
  }
  // Turns light on or off
  @objc func toggleTorch(on: Bool ) {
    guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video) else { return }
    if device.hasTorch {
      if device.isTorchAvailable {
          do {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()

            if on == true {
              do {
              try device.setTorchModeOn(level: 0.5)

              } catch { print("Could not set torch level") }
              device.torchMode = .on

            } else {
              device.torchMode = .off

            }
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
          } catch {
            print("Torch could not be used")
          }
      } else {
          print( "torch unavailable")
      }
    } else {
      print("torch unavailable")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some things I would try:

- Getting the `AVCaptureDevice` and locking its configuration every time you want to toggle the torch is certainly wasting time. Get the device once, put it in an ivar, and lock its configuration once, rather than on every call to `toggleTorch(on:)`.
- [AVFoundation is at least somewhat multithread-capable](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html), so possibly you could async-dispatch the call to `setTorchModeOn` to a non-main queue. I have no idea if this is safe or not, but it's worth a try.
- Use a `DispatchSourceTimer` instead of an `NSTimer`, with the `.strict` option and a minimal `leeway`. The system will make more of an effort to call you on time.

On the other hand, I won't be surprised if those don't help. I don't think the iPhone torch is meant to be used as a 120 Hz strobe.

You may recall the recent kerfuffle about iOS throttling CPU speed on some iPhones with old batteries. iOS does this because otherwise, sudden bursts of activity can try to draw so much power that the battery can't keep up, and the system abruptly shuts off. So we can guess that before turning on the torch, iOS checks the battery level and recent power consumption and perhaps shuts off or slows down some parts of the system (software and hardware) to “make room” for the torch.

Also, from the `isTorchAvailable` documentation:

> The torch may become unavailable if, for example, the device overheats and needs to cool off.

So we can also guess that iOS checks the hardware temperature before turning on the torch.

These checks and actions take some amount of time to execute; possibly several milliseconds. So with this knowledge, it's not surprising that iOS cannot flash the torch at 120 Hz or more.

There's also the question of whether the torch can physically cycle that quickly. When used as a steady-on torch, it doesn't need to turn on or off particularly fast. When used as a camera flash, it is powered by a capacitor that takes time to charge and then delivers a burst of power.